# Why multi dim array içn c return me an error

Tags: c, arrays

I have a probleme with my code. My application return me and error when I run it.

my code

```
    #include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#undef _POSIX_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#include "ini.h"

void readIniFile()
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    char lines [255][255];
    char **tokens;
    static const char filename[] = "../../conf/incoming_files_description.ini"; 
    FILE *file = fopen( filename, "r" );
    if ( file != NULL )
    {
        char line[256];
        while (fgets(line, sizeof line, file) != NULL)
        {
            i++;
            if(i>6) //afficher a partir de la ligne 7
            {
                printf("\n");
                tokens = str_split(line, ';');
                for (j = 0; j<5; j++ )
                {
                lines [i-6][j] = "bonjour";
                printf("%s", lines [1][1]);
                printf("test: %s\n", *(tokens + j));
                free(*(tokens + j));
                }
            }
        }

        fclose (file);
    }
    else
    {
        perror(filename);
    }
}
```

i have a prolem in this line 
                    printf("%s", lines [1][1]); 
when he have valor in lines he return error thx

Comment: Can you state exactly what error it is?

Comment: `printf`'s `%s` expects a `char *`, while `lines[1][1]` is a `char`. My guess is that you want to use: `printf("%c", lines[1][1]);`

Comment: he just show me that
                    process return -1

Comment: when i try your solution Kninnug my program run but my char in lines[1][1] = " " ... one space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
lines [i-6][j] = "bonjour";
```

Actually puts the pointer to the string "bonjour" into the buffer. You are probably wanting to use the strcpy() function to actually copy the string into the buffer. In this particular case you would therefore use

```
strcpy(dest, src);
```

which in this case is

```
strcpy(lines[i-6], "bonjour"]
```

That is the first dimension of lines points to the start of the second dimension which will contain the string. In this case i == 7 so i-6 == 1.

If you want the b of bonjour to go into lines[1][1], then you would need to specify &(lines[1][1]) which points to the address on that location in the buffer.

```
printf("%s", lines [1][1]);
```

Once you copy the string into the buffer you want to pass the pointer to the start of the string in the buffer. Since you would have used strcpy(), then you can print the entire string.

```
printf("%s", lines[1]);
```

Note that lines[1][1] contains the o of bonjour because C uses 0 based indexing unless you made the dest parameter of strcpy() point to the second element of lines[1].